# Code behaves differently on two different network type

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-networking

I have following code for testing the server connectivity.
I have a device that has Ethernet as well as Wi-fi connectivity.

When user switch network from Ethernet to wifi or vise verse, i do the test for server connectivity and i check if my server is reachable or not with the new network.

I have following code:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity
{
    Button test_btn = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        test_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.testButton);
        test_btn.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Log.d("TestApp", "onClick Starting Test");
                startTest();
            }
        });
    } 

    void startTest()
    { 
        ServerTestThread mServerTestThread = new ServerTestThread()
        mServerTestThread.start();
    }

    class ServerTestThread extends Thread 
    {
        boolean result = false;
        public void run() 
        {   
             boolean result = false;
             HttpGet request = new HttpGet("www.MyServer.com");
             HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
             HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

             try
             {
                 HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 6000);
                 HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 6000); 
                 HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

                 int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                 if (status == HttpStatus.SC_OK) 
                 {
                     result = true;
                 }
             }
             catch(Exception e)
             {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 result = false;
             }

             Log.d("TestApp", "Ping Result:"+result);
        }
    }

}
```

This code works fine on my device when i connect my device to internet using Ethernet connectivity, but when i switch from Ethernet to WI-FI this code gives me false result every time.

Using wi-fi i am able to ping to MyServer using the android browser, but from my application i am not able to ping to my server.

Do i need to add something extra to my code to make it work for wifi and Ethernet?

I have also Tried to with `InetAddress.getByName("www.MyServer.com").isReachable(timeout)` but it also giving me the same results.

Is there any reliable way of implementing ping in Android which will work across differnt platforms.

Comment: try with http: //www.MyServer.com

Comment: I have tried it but same behavior.

Comment: Try to use ConnectivityManager.

Comment: `ConnectivityManager` will not tell me if my server is reachable or not, it will just tell me if there is network or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry use this one

```
class ServerTestThread extends Thread 
{
boolean result = false;
public void run() 
{   
     boolean result = false;
     HttpGet request = new HttpGet("www.MyServer.com");
     HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();


     try
     {
         HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 6000);
         HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 6000); 
         HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);///write this line below  
         HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

         int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
         if (status == HttpStatus.SC_OK) 
         {
             result = true;
         }
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
         result = false;
     }

     Log.d("TestApp", "Ping Result:"+result);
}
```

}

Comment: I tried it but i am getting the same behavior, can you please explain the cause and how it will work using above provided solution.